# theme.xml file blank while XML Team Mode is ON [CodenameOne]

Tags: xml, themes, codenameone

From last few days almost every day I got error of corrupt theme file. I need to make copy of `theme.rec` file before opening designer window. In my last question hear about `XML Team Mode` to solve error, but I noticed that even after `XML Team Mode` is `ON` still am facing same problem. While searching in directory I got `theme.xml` file which is blank.

So, I want to know that is this problem in my configuration or this issue is with CodenameOne.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really guess much from the content of the question and amount of information provided but I'll try to answer a more general question:

Team mode opens the XML files under the res directory (not file) that resides beside the src directory.

If you saved a file with the team mode off, these XML files won't be updated and the file will remain blank.

Open the file without the team mode, then switch it on and save to try and generate the XMLs.

You can review these XMLs to see what's going on in your resource files and you can also run the designer from command line to try an figure out potential issues.